# Looping cursor throws error that cursor is not defined

Tags: oracle, plsql

> **I want to loop results from stored procedure. My code:**

```
set serveroutput on
VAR c_curs refcursor;

EXECUTE pck_prov.get_value_type_list(1, :c_curs);


BEGIN
    FOR record_test IN c_curs LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(record_test.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**I don't understand why this is throwing error that c_curs must be declared:**

> > Error starting at line : 7 in command - BEGIN
> >
> > ```
> > FOR record_test IN c_curs LOOP
> >
> >     dbms_output.put_line(record_test.id);
> >
> > END LOOP;
> > ```
> >
> > END;
> >     Error report -
> >
> > ORA-06550: line 2, column 24:
> >
> > PLS-00201: identifier 'C_CURS' must be declared

Answer (score 2):

The cursor can be reference in a PL/SQL block as follows:

```
set serveroutput on    
DECLARE
  c_curs    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id      NUMBER;
BEGIN

  pck_prov.get_value_type_list (1, c_curs); --> procedure called here

  LOOP 
    FETCH c_curs
    INTO  v_id;
    EXIT WHEN c_curs%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_curs;
END;
/
```

Comment: ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match - I guess this is because there are several columns in the table and cursor is being fetched into number.

Comment: your solution is working great, the only thing that I've had to add is number of columns in this line: INTO v_id, name. So, number of columns now match number of returned columns. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: perhaps you know how to create row based on cursor?

Comment: @FrenkyB Right, the return type and number of columns of cursor output should match with the varibles in the INTO clause.

Comment: @FrenkyB I think you don't need to donthis way then. You just need to display the result.I see you posted another question, so I have replied there.

Answer (score 1):

`c_curs` is a bind variable and is not a PL/SQL defined variable. To use it in a PL/SQL block you need to prefix it with a colon `:` to indicate that you are using a bind variable (exactly as you did in the `EXECUTE` statement):

```sql
set serveroutput on
VAR c_curs refcursor;

EXECUTE pck_prov.get_value_type_list(1, :c_curs);


BEGIN
    FOR record_test IN :c_curs LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(record_test.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your solution would be greate because it fetches into row. But I have error PLS-00456: item 'SQLDEVBIND1Z_1' is not a cursor. Is the same code working for you?