# Create record from refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to create record from refcursor. My code:

```
set serveroutput on    
DECLARE
  c_curs    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id      NUMBER;
BEGIN

  pck_prov.get_value_type_list (1, c_curs); --> procedure called here
  -- I guess this is the place where record can be created from cursor.

  LOOP 
    FETCH c_curs
    INTO  v_id;--instead of fetching into variable I would like to fetch into row
    EXIT WHEN c_curs%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id);--if fetching is done into row, only selected columns can be printed, like myrow.id
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_curs;
END;
```

Please note: I know how to create record from cursor which is defined with select statement as it is described [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_DS56PGSKL36JGEFOD5TZIA8PU.html). What I don't know is how to use same technique for refcursors.

**EDIT:**

Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309864/867703) is just what I need, but it throws error:

```
set serveroutput on
VAR c_curs refcursor;

EXECUTE pck_prov.get_value_type_list(1, :c_curs);


BEGIN
    FOR record_test IN :c_curs LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(record_test.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error: error PLS-00456: item 'SQLDEVBIND1Z_1' is not a cursor.

**Just to clarify question:**

In my database there is around 200 packages.
Every package has several stored procedures inside - and usually each procedure is combined with columns from different tables. That is why it would be the best to have some dynamically created cursor, so I can make simple select just like in the example I've posted.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about variable and row here. The variable will hold only a single value of a single column of the cursor. So, if your cursor returns 3 columns, then you need to have 3 variables declared `INTO v_id, name, dept`. Then you mention the same as `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id || ', ' || name || ', ' || dept)`

Comment: @LalitKumarB - yes, I understand this. My problem is that I have stored procedure which returns over 50 columns from different tables. And I need to show only some of them. That is why fetching into row created from cursor would be much easier.

Comment: It might depend on what you want the record for. You can't have a PL/SQL record with a definition that isn't known until runtime, but you can have XML, JSON, CSV etc.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle `12.1` onward, you could use the `DBMS_SQL.return_result` procedure. SQL Plus displays the contents of **implicit statement results** automatically. So, rather than defining explicit ref cursor out parameters, the `RETURN_RESULT` procedure in the DBMS_SQL package allows you to pass them out implicitly.

```
DECLARE
  c_curs    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_id      NUMBER;
BEGIN

  pck_prov.get_value_type_list (1, c_curs);

  DBMS_SQL.return_result(c_curs); --> Passes ref cursor output implicitly
END;
/
```

In fact, no need of this separate PL/SQL block, you could add the `DBMS_SQL.return_result(c_curs)` statement in your original `pck_prov.get_value_type_list` procedure itself.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know it. Is it possible to loop over results somehow and print just desired columns?

Comment: Yes you could do that manually. My answer does that automatically for you. To loop through and display, you could do somrthing like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id || ', ' || name || ', ' || dept)`.

Comment: See example here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Answer (score 1):

Just define a PL/SQL `RECORD` type that matches the cursor and `FETCH` into it.

```
DECLARE
  c_curs    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE rec_t IS RECORD ( object_name VARCHAR2(30), object_type VARCHAR2(30) );
  v_rec     rec_t;
BEGIN

  OPEN c_curs FOR 
       SELECT object_name, 
              object_type 
       FROM   dba_objects 
       WHERE  object_name like 'DBA%TAB%';  

  LOOP 
    FETCH c_curs
    INTO  v_rec;
    EXIT WHEN c_curs%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec.object_name || ' - ' || v_rec.object_type);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_curs;
END;
```

> ```
> DBA_ADVISOR_SQLA_TABLES - VIEW
> DBA_ADVISOR_SQLA_TABVOL - VIEW
> DBA_ADVISOR_SQLW_TABLES - VIEW
> DBA_ADVISOR_SQLW_TABVOL - VIEW
> DBA_ALL_TABLES - VIEW
> etc...
> ```

Comment: But there is no other way, where explicit definition of the record would not be needed? I am asking this because I have around 50 columns (in one example, there is several examples where I need this) and I later usually need to display only several of those columns.

Comment: You could declare the cursor for the select statement and then make `v_rec` of type `c_curs%ROWTYPE`

Comment: But my select is from stored procedure inside package.

Comment: Define the cursor in the package spec of that package.  That will make it visible publicly.

Comment: any example on this?

Comment: I also have problem because there is more than 200 packages inside database. Should I create cursor inside every package? That is why dynamic cursor creation would be great.

Comment: You say you want to get ref cursor rows into 200 different statically-typed PL/SQL record types.  I don't understand how you want to that to work without defining the types.  Do all 200 types have some common column(s) or something that want to extract?  Otherwise, maybe update you question with a little more detail on how you intend to consume these PL/SQL records once you get them.

Comment: Every package has several stored procedures inside - and usually each procedure is combined with columns from different tables. That is why it would be the best to have some dynamically created cursor, so I can make simple select just like in the example I've posted.